# First attempt at Magic 8 Ball program, not looping

Tags: python, spyder

This is my first attempt at making a program that acts like a magic 8 ball, however I can't seem to get the program to loop again, that is, I can't get the program to ask the user to input another question after typing in a 'Y'. How do I get the program to ask the user to input another question after typing a 'Y' once their first question is answered?

```
# All the possible Magic 8 Ball responses
response = ["As I see it, yes", "Ask again later", "Better not tell you now", "Cannot predict now", "Concentrate and ask again", "Don't count on it", "It is certain", "It is decidedly so", "Most likely", "My reply is no", "My sources say no", "Outlook not so good", "Outlook good", "Reply hazy, try again", "Signs point to yes", "Very doubtful", "Without a doubt", "Yes", "Yes - definitely", "You may rely on it"]

import math

#C onstants
N = 10000 # The norm
A = 4875  # The adder
M = 8601  # The multiplier

X = input("Enter a YES or NO question: ")
S = int(input("Now enter an integer: "))
K = 1
print("The Magic 8 Ball says:")
# -----------------------------------------
# The pseudorandom number generator

keep_going = 'Y'

while keep_going == 'Y':
    for i in range(K):
        S = (S * M + A) % N # Random Number Generator
        r = S/N #On the interval [0,1)
        magic = math.floor(20 *r)
        print(response[magic])

        #Asking the user if they want to ask another question
        keep_going = input('Do you want to ask another question ' +
                           'question? (Enter Y for yes and N for no): ')
```

Comment: You must ask the question in the while-loop (and some other code must be placed in it, too). The for-loop is by the way useless here.

Comment: Welcome on SO! To increase probability of getting answers I suggest minimizing your code example by removing lines, which do not cause problem to vanish. The shorter your code sample is, the quicker you get help as it is easier to understand your problem. See: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
#All the possible Magic 8 Ball responses
response = ["As I see it, yes", "Ask again later", "Better not tell you now", "Cannot predict now", "Concentrate and ask again", "Don't count on it", "It is certain", "It is decidedly so", "Most likely", "My reply is no", "My sources say no", "Outlook not so good", "Outlook good", "Reply hazy, try again", "Signs point to yes", "Very doubtful", "Without a doubt", "Yes", "Yes - definitely", "You may rely on it"]

import math

#Constants
N = 10000 #The norm
A = 4875 #The adder
M = 8601 #The multiplier

K = 1
print("The Magic 8 Ball says:")
#-----------------------------------------
#The pseudorandom number generator

keep_going = 'Y'

while keep_going in ['y', 'Y']: # allow for lower case 'y'
    X = input("Enter a YES or NO question: ") # moved question into loop
    S = int(input("Now enter an integer: "))
    for i in range(K):
        S = (S * M + A) % N #Random Number Generator
        r = S/N #On the interval [0,1)
        magic = math.floor(20 *r)
        print(response[magic])

        #Asking the user if they want to ask another question
        keep_going = input('Do you want to ask another question ' +
                           'question? (Enter Y for yes and N for no): ')
```

Comment: What will exactly happen when OP tries this? What did you change?

Answer (score 0):

Beside the comment about asking again the questions, here is your problem:

```
while keep_going == 'Y':
```

when you type y to continue is lower case y, and not upper case Y, you should change it so it doesn't matter if is lower o upper case.

Comment: You can do that by writing `while keep_going.lower() == 'Y':`

Comment: Although arguably entering `y` violates the prompt and so would rightfully be rejected. But it's by far not the most serious problem with this code.

Comment: @A.Pond: —but that's just mean, suggesting a comparison that always will return `False`...

Comment: Oh, you right. `while keep_going.lower() == 'y''`: my b